# Can't solve not wrapped in act error in react testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch-api, react-testing-library

I use fetch in my functional component, so of course I have a state update too. In the tests I use mocked fetch, which returns my own fake data. Here is the 3 test case I have:

1. check if fetch was called (only have an expect wrapped in waitfor)
2. check if data is displayed correctly (checks if fake data is displayed, it it wrapped in waitfor)
3. check if after click on element it directs to a fake url (it has a userEvent.click for the element then it checks for the new url which is also part of the fake data that is returned by fetch. it is wrapped in waitfor)

Even though I use waitfor and all the 3 tests pass I still have 3 not wrapped in act error. What could be the problem?

UPDATE: Here is the 3rd tests code as an example

```
const savedLocation = window.location;
jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch');
const fakeData = { "articles" : [{
    title: "title",
    url: "url",
    desc: "desc"
}]};

beforeEach(() => {
    delete window.location;
    window.location = { assign: jest.fn() };
    window.fetch.mockResolvedValueOnce({ json: () => fakeData });
    render(<Router><Home /></Router>);
});

afterEach(() => {
    window.location = savedLocation;
});

it("fetch is called", async () => {
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});

it("article is displayed with correct data", async () => {
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(screen.getByRole('heading')).toHaveTextContent('title');
        expect(screen.getByTestId('desc')).toHaveTextContent('desc');
    });
});

it("click on article calls window.location.assign with fake url", async () => {
    await waitFor(() => {
        userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('artCont'));
        expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeData.articles[0].url);
    });
});
```

Note that artCont is the div container inside which the title and description of the fetched data is displayed. Clicking on that div changes the url. Also I delete the window.location to be able to check for the assign function since it can't be mocked anymore in newer versions, but I don't know if it has something to do with the 3 errors I get.

Comment: Impossible to fix without code

Comment: Just updated. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I guess that the error comes from the test with click

Comment: Just added all the tests, hope it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Your `waitFor`s  don't do anything. I would remove them. If you still getting an error, the last one with `act(() => { })` and see what happens

Comment: I already tried to remove the waitFors. In case of the first test, it passed but still got the not wrapped in act error. In case of 2nd and 3rd test, they failed, because it looked for elements that hasn't displayed yet. Also tried using act but it did not help either, causes failing tests.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, which appeared after introducing async state updates (I'm using redux and RTK).

Wrapping `render` in [`act`](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) fixed this for me.

I'm not sure this is *the* solution or if it's a good approach, but it took a ton of digging, WFM, and it's info I could have used earlier, so I'll share it:

```
await act(() =>
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ItemList />
    </Provider>
  )
);
// At this point all state changes have finished rendering,
// including async ones triggered during rendering itself.
// Speculation: Without act(), the Promises would resolve outside
// the original render(), triggering state and DOM changes,
// and that causes the error messages.

expect(screen.getByRole('heading')).toHaveTextContent('title');
```

This way I don't need to use any `waitFor` or `await findBy..` magic either (common suggestions when searching for this problem): plain `getBy..` always works now.

I also need to wrap redux dispatches in `act`, as they trigger DOM changes too:

```
await act(() => store.dispatch(itemSelected(itemKey)));
```

If someone can correct me, explain better, or corroborate this, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Still getting an "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression." warning, but the act warning is no longer present.